# Dates go crazy when applying pd.to_datetime

Tags: python

I have this situation in which I have a DataFrame with a string column with some values with this format:

```
DD/MM/YYYY
```

and some with this other one:

```
DD/MM/YYYY HH:Mi:SS
```

If I try to convert everything to datetime like this

```
df['COLUMN'] = pd.to_datetime(df['COLUMN'])
```

The rows without the HH:Mi:SS go crazy and the months are interpreted as days (and viceversa).
How could avoid this and have a column with just date format?

Example of column which goes crazy:

Before conversion:
DateTime
--------
02/07/2021
15/07/2021  18:16:00

After conversion:

```
DateTime
    2021-02-07 (This is February!!)
    2021-07-15  18:16:00
```

Comment: Use a slice which only contains the date: `df['COLUMN'] = pd.to_datetime(df['COLUMN'].str[:10])` Or exact = False: `pd.to_datetime(df.Column, format='%d/%m/%Y', exact=False)`

Comment: To preserve the time portion: `pd.to_datetime(df.date, infer_datetime_format=True)` ... [the docs are your freind](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas `to_datetime` has an inbuild parameter to specify if your day is first. i.e. `dayfirst`

You can use it as :

```
df['COLUMN'] = pd.to_datetime(df['COLUMN'], dayfirst=True)
```

Checkout the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following achieves the desired output (may not be the fastest way)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['15/07/2021 18:16:00', '02/07/2021']})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d/%m/%Y', errors='coerce').fillna(pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S", errors="coerce"))
print(df.head())
for date in df['date']:
    print(type(date))
```

Output:

```
                 date
0 2021-07-15 18:16:00
1 2021-07-02 00:00:00
<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
```